# Android Studio Gradle Product Flavors

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I would like to have a ADMIN and AUDIENCE version of each Product Flavor,
how will the build file look?

so far I have....

```
   productFlavors {

    app1 {
        applicationId 'com.example.channel.1'
    }

    app2{
        applicationId 'com.example.channel.2'
    }

    app3{
        applicationId 'com.example.channel.3'
    }

    app4{
        applicationId 'com.example.channel.4'
    }

 }
```

My Goal is to achieve this type of source code structure....

```
   app1ADMIN
     src/

   app1AUDIENCE
     src/

   app2ADMIN
     src/

   app2AUDIENCE
     src
```

I tried putting audience and admin in buildtypes, but it didnt produce release and debug variants...

Now I am trying.....

```
   flavorDimensions 'audience', 'admin'


productFlavors {

    app1 {
        applicationId 'com.example.audience.app1'
        flavorDimension "audience"

    }

    app1D {
        applicationId 'com.example.admin.app1'
        flavorDimension "admin"

    }
```

This one didn't work at all, it produced.

```
    app1Dapp1
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `src` create directories `app1ADMIN,...` then change `build.gradle` for THIS PROJECT (not root one) to look like this

```
productFlavors {
    app1ADMIN {
        packageName "xxx"
    }
    app1AUDIENCE {
        packageName "yyy"
    }
    app2ADMIN {
        packageName "zzz"
    }
    app2AUDIENCE {
        packageName "ooo"
    }
}
```

Comment: thats pretty much what I have now. But I know there's a iller way to freak it tho.

Comment: @sirvon Not at this moment, nothing simpler